# Windows Server 2008 64bit boot problems after power outage

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

We had a power outage over the weekend due to some storms.  All servers went down, and eventually came back up fine.  All accept for one.  Tried rebooting it, but took hours to apply computer settings and network settings before getting to the CTL ALT DEL screen.

Did login, but that as well took about 2 hours to finally reach the desktop.  Digging around, 80% of services didn't start, cannot get to network properties, WSUS, any applications, cannot remote to it, etc

Dug around through event viewer but didn't find anything that would be of assistance to what is going on.

Yesterday, I was able to boot up into safe mode fine and quickly.  Checked around then, but didn't find anything.  Rebooted again and same results getting into windows normally.

I am looking for any suggestions..  Thank you.  In the meantime, I am going to bounce it again and go into safe mode and see if I can run windows updates from safe mode.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.  This is my backup server so I need to get my backups running again...

Comment: have you checked the hardware/ran Diagnostics? maybe the Raid array is badly degraded or some other hardware problem causing it to be so slow.

Comment: I was just chatting with my manager and he suggested the smart start CD to run diagnostics.  So I am going to try that now.  Seems like there is some hardware failure somewhere.

Good suggestions, thanks...

Comment: Were these servers on a UPS?

Comment: Yes on a UPS, but power out too long.  We don't have enough UPS to power for very long, more for those short blips during a storm.

Comment: smartstart diagnostics show all hardware is testing out fine.

Comment: In the future you probably want to set up some type of graceful shutdown of the servers if they've been on UPS power for too long. If you're using APC UPS units (depending on the model) then APC has software for this purpose. If you're not able to set this up for some reason then you probably want to invest in some type of power monitor that can alert you via email\pager\sms so that you can log in and power down each server.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to assess for possible file system damage, especially since you are experiencing boot difficulties - chkdsk...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a misbehaving service. Boot into safe mode. Run msconfig. Disable all non-microsoft services and startup items. Reboot normally. If it comes up fine, start enabling needed services one by one until you find the culprit. If it doesn't come up fine, you may have to repair your OS or certain roles. What roles are installed on this server? What 3rd part apps?

Answer (score 0):

Normal behavior. Under certain circumstances after an outage the first start is SLOW, because of checking operations / resync or RAID going on  - and because of nor domain controller being available.

Comment: I would doubt a disk or RAID problem as that would affect a safe mode login as well. I suspect an OS or network problem here.

Comment: Disk array is fine, tested.

Answer (score 0):

since it came up fine under safe boot, I'd think the problem is network related as in the nic or the port on the switch is failing/failed!

Answer (score 0):

try unplugging the cable and plug it back in
if that helps - ok
otherwise - delete the nic from device manager
reboot windows - let it install itself or provide the drivers